# Anyone using ASP.NET MembershipProvider with Nhibernate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, postgresql, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to implement Membership controls in a mvc 2 application and i'm having trouble dealing with the MembershipUser class.

I have my own data store (in Postgresql) and I'm using Nhibernate to deal with it from C#. The thing is, I have my own user class, but I can't use it with any provider I found that implements Membership, because all the functions return the predefined MembershipUser class and cannot return my own.

I'm losing my mind here, is there any way i can work with this, or should I implement everything myself?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [NHibernate Membership Provider](http://nhmemberprovider.codeplex.com/) project and use it as a base to build from.

Answer (score 1):

You must derive from the `MembershipUser` class and `override` the methods you wish to replace.